# How to get focus for a button in between two editfields in android

Tags: android

i am having a button in between two edit fields. when iam using track ball to scroll ,button is getting focus but when i use the next button in softkeyboard after typing some text in editfield , focus is moving on to next editfield but not the button inbetween them .how to solve this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:focusableInTouchMode` attribute:

```
<Button ...  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:nextFocusDown` and `android:nextFocusUp` solves your problem.